# keep only one row per grouped column based on column value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Suppose I have a data.frame in R

```
User  Hardware
a     mac
a     tablet
a     laptop
b     laptop
b     tablet
c     tablet
c     mac
```

If a user has a mac, I want to keep only the mac row, and if a user does not have a mac keep all of the rows.

My desired output

```
User Hardware
a    mac
b    laptop
b    tablet
c    mac
```

I have been searching and trying, but unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This removes from `df` the non-mac rows of users which have macs.

```
df = read.table(text="User  hardware
a       mac
a       tablet
a       laptop
b       laptop
b       tablet
c       tablet
c       mac", header = TRUE)

mac_users = as.character(unique(df$User[df$hardware == "mac"]))
df = df[!((df$User %in% mac_users) & (df$hardware != "mac")),]
```